# Knockout Javascript Select Mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Looked at a lot of stackoverflow examples but to no avail. I have a javascript array of strings which I wish to map to a ko observableArray, which I then want to apply to a select in my HTML. Here is the main ko object:

```
actionData: {
    json: false,
    xml: false,
    pdf: false,
    word: false,
    csv: false,
    excel: false,
    prophet: false,
    editablePdf: false,
    editableWord: false,
    zip: false,
    httpUrl: null,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    connectionTest: false,
    requiredAlerts: [],
    folder: null,
    first: null,
    libraries: []
},
```

Then when my ajax call returns with the data I map it. At this point I have verified that it is happy (see the "first" variable has have the proper data when I look at it the debugger):

```
var list = JSON.parse(data.libraries);
self.CurrentAction.actionData.libraries = ko.observableArray(list);
//self.CurrentAction.actionData.folder = ko.observable();
self.CurrentAction.actionData.first = ko.observable(list[0]);
var first = self.CurrentAction.actionData.libraries()[0];
```

Finally in my .CSHTML I do the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2" data-bind="with: CurrentAction.actionData">
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input class="format-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: editablePdf"> Make PDF document editable</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><label><input class="format-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: editableWord"> Make Word document editable</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" data-bind="with: CurrentAction.actionData">
        <label>LIB</label>
        <input data-bind="value: first">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
    <label>SharePoint Library</label>
    <!-- ko with: CurrentAction.actionData. -->
    <select data-bind="options : libraries,
                        value : folder,
                        optionsCaption : 'Please choose a SharePoint Library...'"
            style="width: 100%; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #AAAAAA;">
    </select>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <p style="font-size: 13px; margin-top: 5px;">Your files will be sent to this library when submitted</p>
</div>
```

And I get nothing in the select. I have verifies that other elements in the construct are there, but for some reason the "libraries" is not or I am mapping it incorrectly?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the great answers below I have figured it all out. Basically I had a few problems:

1. My `actionData` was actually mapping to another object which was missing the `library` object. This was due to some other code that I was unaware of. Once I got that fixed the data started to map/bind correctly
2. Once I had the correct object the `library` was already an observeableArray, so there was no need to re-map it to observable. The new code looks like:

`if (data.statusCode == "200") {
    var list = JSON.parse(data.libraries);
    self.CurrentAction.actionData.libraries(list);
 }`

3. Finally, the previous incorrect object had been persisted, so when I ran again the old object persisted (incorrect) data was being loaded and ruining everything.

The final HTML version looks like this:

```
       <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
            <label>SharePoint Library</label>
            <select data-bind="options : CurrentAction.actionData.libraries,
                               value : CurrentAction.actionData.folder,
                               optionsCaption : 'Please choose a SharePoint Library...'"
                    style="width: 100%; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #AAAAAA;">
                <option data-bind="text: Name"></option>
            </select>
            <p style="font-size: 13px; margin-top: 5px;">Your files will be sent to this library when submitted</p>
        </div>
```

Many thanks for the great answers!

Comment: Can you show more of your javascript? The structure of your binding contexts isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite following your question but I used your data and mapped it to a select using the options binding it seemed to work ok.  run snippet below

```js
var data = {
  json: false,
  xml: false,
  pdf: false,
  word: false,
  csv: false,
  excel: false,
  prophet: false,
  editablePdf: false,
  editableWord: false,
  zip: false,
  httpUrl: null,
  username: null,
  password: null,
  connectionTest: false,
  requiredAlerts: [],
  folder: 'three',
  first: null,
  libraries: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options : libraries,
                        value : folder,
                        optionsCaption : 'Please choose a SharePoint Library...'" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #AAAAAA;">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. That helped me solve my first issue - looks like the object I was using did not initially define "libraries". The real issue I have now is that when I populate the "libraries" list from my ajax call - does not seem to bind. However if I run it a second time the data shows up in the control. Do I need to rebind when populating? I have updated the code to show the current state of the code. thanks